# Find another record if a record meet the checking in a MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

My table looks like this:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
-----+------+-------
1    | a    | 0
2    | b    | 0
3    | c    | 1
4    | a    | 1
5    | a    | 0
```

My requirement is:

```
1. find all records from the table where col2 = 'a' 
2. For those results whose col3 = 1, ALSO find their previous record whose col3 is not 1
```

by previous record, I mean the numeric sequence in col1. For example, for record of col1 = 5, its previous record is record of col1=4

How can get this done in a MYSQL query?

Comment: define `previous record`

Comment: by `previous record`, I mean the numeric sequence in col1. For example, for record of col1 = 5, its previous record is record of col1=4.

Comment: do you have gaps on col1?

Comment: I was thinking to do it on the app side. First, call a query to find all the record from the table where col2 = 'a', and then Foreach(result) { if(col3 == 1) call another query to find the corresponding record}. However, I don't want to call the db server so many times. Therefore, I am wondering if there is any better way do it in one query (may be a long long query)

Comment: So basically you want to return rows 1, 2, 4, & 5 - rows 1, 4, and 5 satisfy requirement 1, and row 2 satisfies requirement 2,

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, if you don't have gaps on your col1 column, could be like this:

```
select
  *
from
  tablename
where
  col1 in (select col1 from tablename where col2='a'
           union all
           select col1-1 from tablename where col2='a' and col3='1')
```